# How to configure WebSphere to sync with LDAP on regular period?

Tags: configuration, ldap, websphere

I've been searching online, and specifically on IBM's site, but have not yet found where WebSphere configures its setting for regular/periodic syncs with its LDAP repository.  I've heard that on some regular/periodic default interval (30 mins maybe?), WebSphere will update itself with the data in its LDAP repository.  This is to account for updates being made to the LDAP repository outside of WebSphere's control.  Anyone know where in WebSphere this interval setting is configured?

Comment: Is this for authentication and authorization? AIUI this is not so much a sync operation as it is on-demand queries with configurable caching (this is how nearly every LDAP-enabled application works).  For example, federated LDAP tuning: http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=matt&product=was-nd-dist&topic=twim_performance

Comment: I also originally thought that it was only on-demand.  This is for authentication/authorization.  My colleague had had the impression that there was such a setting for LDAP synchronization, but he's since been convinced otherwise and concurs with your explanation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default WAS will sync with LDAP and update the user and group information into cache.
This cache timeout was set to 10 mins by default. When the cache timeout expires, all cached information not accessed within the timeout period is purged from the cache.
Again WAS will sync with LDAP server and fetch information and stored in cache.

Global security > Authentication cache settings

Answer (score 0):

There is no such setting for LDAP synchronization with WebSphere.  Explains why I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. It seems that WAS keeps search results for some time in cache. Solution is to setup low LDAP cache timeouts. Navigate here: Global security > Federated repositories > LDAP1 > Performance